# How do I expose the existing @bind- property of Blazorise TextEdit from a custom razor component

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor, blazorise

How does one bind to the Blazorise components, in this case to get validation working?

```
<Validation>
    <Field>
        <FieldLabel>Name</FieldLabel>
        <TextEdit Placeholder="Enter your name here"
                  @bind-Text="@DataRecord.Person.Name"
                  ReadOnly="false"
                  Disabled="false">
            <Feedback>
                <FieldHelp>A valid name will be 3-100 characters long.</FieldHelp>
                <ValidationError />
            </Feedback>
        </TextEdit>
    </Field>
</Validation>
```

And the above code will repeat multiple times within the page depending on the number of fields that I have...

So I tried creating a custom razor component called `<ValidatedTextEdit>` which contained the following code:

```
<Validation>
    <Field>
        <FieldLabel>@FieldLabelText</FieldLabel>
        <TextEdit Placeholder="@FieldPlaceholderText"
                  @bind-Text="@FieldDataSource"
                  ReadOnly="@IsFieldReadOnly"
                  Disabled="@IsFieldDisabled">
            <Feedback>
                <FieldHelp>@FieldHelpText</FieldHelp>
                <ValidationError />
            </Feedback>
        </TextEdit>
    </Field>
</Validation>
```

#### Code Section

```
@code {
    [Parameter] public string FieldLabelText { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter] public string FieldPlaceholderText { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter] public string FieldHelpText { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter] public bool IsFieldReadOnly { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter] public bool IsFieldDisabled { get; set; } = false;
    
    protected string _fieldDataSource;

    [Parameter]
    public string FieldDataSource
    {
        get => _fieldDataSource;
        set
        {
            if (_fieldDataSource == value) return;
            _fieldDataSource = value;
            FieldDataSourceChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> FieldDataSourceChanged { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to use the `<ValidatedTextEdit>` like this:

```
<ValidatedTextEdit FieldLabelText="Name"
                   FieldPlaceholderText="Enter your name here"
                   @bind-FieldDataSource="@DataRecord.Person.Name"
                   FieldHelpText="A valid name will be 3-100 characters long."
                   IsFieldReadOnly="false"
                   IsFieldDisabled="false"/>
```

The problem now is that while the data are stored in the database, both `<Validation>` and `<ValidationError />` does not seem to work...it won't display any error...

Why?

Comment: (There was an answer posted that probably should have been a comment, with a link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-across-more-than-two-components )

Comment: Thank you very much for the response..I did try using this method..and it does indeed save to the database..but unfortunately, it still does not show the validation errors :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing TextExpression. It is needed so that Blazor can pass information about bind field.

```
<Validation>
    <Field>
        <FieldLabel>@FieldLabelText</FieldLabel>
        <TextEdit Placeholder="@FieldPlaceholderText"
                  Text="@FieldDataSource"
                  TextChanged="@FieldDataSourceChanged"
                  TextExpression="@FieldDataSourceExpression"
                  ReadOnly="@IsFieldReadOnly"
                  Disabled="@IsFieldDisabled">
            <Feedback>
                <FieldHelp>@FieldHelpText</FieldHelp>
                <ValidationError />
            </Feedback>
        </TextEdit>
    </Field>
</Validation>
@code {
    [Parameter] public string FieldLabelText { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter] public string FieldPlaceholderText { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter] public string FieldHelpText { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter] public bool IsFieldReadOnly { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter] public bool IsFieldDisabled { get; set; } = false;
    
    protected string _fieldDataSource;

    [Parameter]
    public string FieldDataSource
    {
        get => _fieldDataSource;
        set
        {
            if (_fieldDataSource == value) return;
            _fieldDataSource = value;
            FieldDataSourceChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> FieldDataSourceChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>> FieldDataSourceExpression { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir Mladen, everything works perfectly now!!